# Add Multiple DataFrames and Drop Mismatched Indices

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas [DataFrame.add](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) method has the following note: "Mismatched indices will be unioned together" but I'm looking for the most efficient way to drop mismatched indices.

I have multiple DataFrames, each with a DateTime index, but I only want to add together the values on dates that have observations in *ANY* of the columns in ALL of the DataFrames that I'm adding together. What's the most efficient way to do this (i.e. drop mismatched indices instead of union them)?

```
iso_country_code  AFG AGO ALB       ARE
period_end
2013-03-31        NaN NaN NaN  7.512557
2013-06-30        NaN NaN NaN  7.455903
2013-09-30        NaN NaN NaN  7.232294
2013-12-31        NaN NaN NaN  7.044918
2014-03-31        NaN NaN NaN  7.049269
2014-06-30        NaN NaN NaN  8.621573
2014-09-30        NaN NaN NaN       NaN
2014-12-31        NaN NaN NaN       NaN

iso_country_code       AFG       AGO        ALB        ARE
period_end
2013-03-31        0.083310  4.164154  20.002821  17.463841
2013-06-30        0.092613  5.129979  20.389471  17.774866
2013-09-30        0.048484  5.116080  20.641199  17.535600
2013-12-31        0.067519  3.632584  21.494163  18.122075
2014-03-31        0.242996  3.686424  18.178002  19.399709
2014-06-30             NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
2014-09-30             NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
2014-12-31             NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
```

*** Procedure Complete ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be as easy as:

```
(df1 + df2).dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

if that doesn't work, try:

```
df1.add(df2).dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

I can't test write now, but both (or at least) one of those will leave you with:

```
iso_country_code  ARE
period_end
2013-03-31        25.xxx
2013-06-30        xx.xxx
2013-09-30        xx.xxx
2013-12-31        xx.xxx
2014-03-31        xx.xxx
2014-06-30        xx.xxx
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more specific in my question but really what I want to do is drop rows > '2014-03-31' since I only have data for those periods in one DataFrame.

Comment: Right on. That's where showing the desired output is always very helpful. Just remove the second call to `dropna` to leave all of the columns where thy are.

Comment: Makes sense. I would have assumed 'Mismatched indices will be unioned together' would imply that values would be unioned as well, but I'm noticing in the fill_value parameter the following text: "If both DataFrame locations are missing, the result will be missing". The code you suggested seems to imply that if either of the DataFrame locations are missing, the result will be missing. Or am I way off?

Comment: @idubs11 what I think that means is that NaN + [some real value] = NaN in the resulting dataframe. However, NaN + NaN doesn't get even a seat on the bus.